# wkthmltopdf generates only static html without javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

In my local machine, I am trying to convert an HTML page to a PDF with `wkhtmltopdf`, using `phpwkhtmltopdf` wrapper, however the generated PDF contains the static HTML of the page only, without the Javascript generated html. Consider that:

- The HTML + Javascript displays correctly in the browser.
- The css for the static html code is correctly displayed in the PDF, so I assume that also the javascript is correctly linked to be used for the PDF generation.
- I have already tried with the `--javascript-delay` option without success.
- The javascript loads a `.csv` make some computation and displays the results in a dynamically generated `<table>`.

As an example consider this HTML + javascript code that generates a dummy table in the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My HTML</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>
      document.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
          // create a table
          var tr, td;
          holder = document.createElement('table');
          my_ar = [10, 20, 30];
          // add first row
          for (var x = 0, len = my_ar.length; x < len; ++x) {
            // first row
            if (x === 0) {
              var titles = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
              tr = document.createElement('tr');
              holder.appendChild(tr);
              for (var i = 0, len1 = titles.length; i < len1; ++i) {
                td = document.createElement('th');
                td.innerHTML = titles[i];
                tr.appendChild(td);
              }
            }

            // add other rows
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            holder.appendChild(tr);
            for (var i = 0, len2 = titles.length; i < len2; ++i) {
              td = document.createElement('td');
              td.innerHTML = my_ar[i];
              tr.appendChild(td);
            }
          }

          document.body.appendChild(holder);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
          <a id="print-link" href="path/to/getPdf.php">Print it!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my `getPdf.php` script to make the PDF, called by an `<a>` in the HTML page. The script is inspired by the example shown `phpwkhtmltopdf` page.

```
include_once "./vendor/autoload.php";

use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;


$pdf = new Pdf;
$pdf->binary = 'path/to/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
$pageOptions = array(
    'javascript-delay' => 2000,
    'encoding'         => 'UTF-8',
  );

$pdf->addPage('/path/to/index.html', $pageOptions);

if (!$pdf->send('report.pdf')) {
  throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
}
```

When I click on the print link, a PDF is returned containing the print link, but the table is not displayed.

Comment: Please show the code, else its just a story.

Comment: Did you try to enable javacript script first, `--enable-javascript`

Comment: @YouneL I have tried to add `'enable-javascript'` in `$pageOptions`, but the JS code is still not run.